# Chrome extension not showing up in store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published my chrome extension to the store a couple of hours ago and received the message: "Your item has been published. All changes will take effect within a few minutes." and am yet to see it appear in the store (still seeing this message).

Does it usually take this long for a chrome extension to show up in the store?

Answer (score 9):

When I click "View in Chrome Web Store" link in the new Developer Dashboard I get to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/************************/publish-accepted-testers?authuser=0&hl=en` page:

[image]

But if I click on the extension name in the old Developer Dashboard I get to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension_name/******************` page where `Add to Chrome` button is active.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [webstore developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard), you should be able to click on your extension, that will bring you to its webstore page. You can share this link before your extension gets listed, which often takes a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, and needed to revert to the old developer dashboard (as @Winand mentioned) to get to the correct link in the web store.  Here's a screen shot of how to opt out of the new Chrome Extension Developer Dashboard:

[image]

More info on the Chromium blog here: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/new-developer-dashboard-and.html.

Answer (score -1):

close the the browser and restart it.If still getting prob then go and try again to the more tools and extension .Search it over there ,if enable then restart & use it.